# Test Java class using XML Database

Tags: java, xml, database, object, testing

I am testing a Java Class I created, and to do that, I need some objects from a db.
So I have a XML file containing the information I need about the object.

My XML file is like that (with more attributes):

```
<!-- Users -->
    <public.tb_user id="1" identifiant="superadmin"/>
    <public.tb_user id="2" identifiant="user"/>
    <public.tb_user id="3" identifiant="master"/>
```

I need a User in my testing class. How can I get it ?

Comment: Read and parse the XML and map the data into a User object.  Or you can try JAXB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did not have to get the User from the XML file.
It was way easier to create a new User in the test class directly because I only needed one user